# How to get date which is going to be after 3 months?

Tags: php, date

How do i get 3 months after the date of today in php?

From PHP i'll get todays date by `date("Y-m-d");` lets say `2012-02-22`

How i'll get a date after 3 months.... i.e `2012-05-22`

**EDIT:-**

The issue is about different number of days in different months, feb have 28 days also and 29 in leap... odd months 31 and others 30... Is there any pre-built function in php which i can use to deal with this issue... ??

**EDIT 2**

With all responses i understood that it would be a problem:-

In reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10275921/1182021 [+1]

So i think it would be better of writing a manual function for it... and i'll put it here as an answer... Thanks for everyone help and support..

**ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION**

We need to check all the conditions manually for accurate calculations... there is no inbuilt function for this in PHP.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/10280441/1182021

Comment: What do you expect to get when `2012-01-31` is the input?

Comment: I don't think your question is sufficiently well-defined to answer it. For example, what if today is January 31st? April only has 30 days.

Comment: There's no way we can answer your question, since we don't know *how* you want to deal with it. There might well be a function that does what you want to do, but we don't know what you want. You seem to be asking how to get the right answer to a meaningless question. You need to decide what question you want the answer to first.

Comment: @JackManey I do understand that.... and I know i had not explained the question properly... my mistake... please reconsider i have edited my question.. Thanks

Comment: As the answers have explained, there is no such thing as "3 months after the date". So you are asking how to get something that does not exist. If you tell us what you actually want, perhaps we can tell you how to get it. But we don't know what you want.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I want to know weather i need to write a manual function for this or do php have any inbuilt function to achieve this... Hope its clear

Comment: It's not clear. If you wrote a manual function, what would it do? How could you write a manual function to tell you the date "3 months from today" when there is no such thing?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it will check for the month and accordingly calculate the +3 months, as we can use this to get the month `date('F');` and then will calculate accordingly using loops and if conditions

Comment: So, what would your function output for a date of, say `2011-12-17`?

Comment: @JackManey It has to be `2012-03-17`. I am unable to understand what exactly going on... i need to know is there any inbuilt trick in php to do this stuff or not... and if yes then what... that's it... i appreciate u ppl effort of keeping StackOverflow neat.. but i am too not spoiling it....

Comment: So, why wouldn't it be `2011-15-17`?  Do you see the problem with the question that you're asking?

Comment: @JackManey Ok i am still unable to understand the issue... may be my mistake... will put an answer shortly... writing a manual function... Thanks for your concern and support

Comment: @JackManey Now check this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/10280441/1182021

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Now check this out :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/10280441/1182021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 100% working code to accomplish the task

```
<?php
$month = date('n');
$year = date('Y');
$IsLeapYear = date('L');
$NextYear = $year + 1;
$IsNextYearLeap = date('L', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $NextYear));
$TodaysDate = date('j');
if (strlen($month+3) < 10)
{
    $UpdateMonth = "0".($month+3);
}
if ($month > 9) {
    if ($month == 10)
    {
        $UpdateMonth = "01";
    }
    else if ($month == 11)
    {
        $UpdateMonth = "02";
    }
    else
    {
        $UpdateMonth = "03";
    }
}

if (($month != 10) && ($month != 11) && ($month != 12))
{
    if(($month&1) && ($TodaysDate != 31))
    {
        $DateAfterThreeMonths = $year."-".$UpdateMonth."-".$TodaysDate;
    }
    else if (($month&1) && ($TodaysDate == 31))
    {
        $DateAfterThreeMonths = $year."-".$UpdateMonth."-30";
    } 
    else {
        $DateAfterThreeMonths = $year."-".$UpdateMonth."-".$TodaysDate;
    }
}
else if ($month == 11)
{
    if (($TodaysDate == 28) || ($TodaysDate == 29) || ($TodaysDate == 30))
    {
        if ($IsLeapYear == 1)
        {
            $DateAfterThreeMonths = ($year+1)."-".$UpdateMonth."-28";
        }
        else if ($IsNextYearLeap == 1)
        {
            $DateAfterThreeMonths = ($year+1)."-".$UpdateMonth."-29";
        }
        else
        {
            $DateAfterThreeMonths = ($year+1)."-".$UpdateMonth."-28";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $DateAfterThreeMonths = ($year+1)."-".$UpdateMonth."-".$TodaysDate;
    }
}
else
{
    $DateAfterThreeMonths = ($year+1)."-".$UpdateMonth."-".$TodaysDate;
}
echo $DateAfterThreeMonths; 
?>
```

We can check the stuff manually by using this piece of code in top:-

```
// Just change the values of $month, $year, $TodaysDate
$month = 11;
$year = 2012;
$IsLeapYear = date('L');
$NextYear = $year + 1;
$IsNextYearLeap = date('L', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $NextYear));
$TodaysDate = 31;
```

**Just copy and paste the code, check it in your browser :)**

Comment: I might have not explained the question properly.... but its not that i am here to create mess...

Comment: This solution doesn't work; it doesn't work for months 10, 11, or 12, and the formatting is broken too. There is also a lot of inflexible, hardcoded logic in there!

Comment: Did it occur to you that maybe there's a better way to do this...?

Comment: @AbhilashShukla If you tell us what you're actually trying to achieve with this, we may be able to suggest a better approach. It seems like you might be trying to solve the wrong problem!

Comment: @WillVousden Can you please explain me the problem, that what is wrong with 10, 11 and 12?? And what that formatting issue?? Because it looks me fine and its working.... Still if you can suggest me a better way to do this...

Comment: @WillVousden I'll try to put things in a better way... may be you could help... I have a product registration page, where i register products and give service after three months from that date... Now when a product is reg on `NOV 29 or 30 or 31` and the next year is not a `Leap Year` automatically it should be assigned to `Feb 28` and if its `OCT or DEC` there is no need to check as there will be no date issue...

Comment: @JackManey Seriously man, i know it can be done in a better way and that's why i put up the question here... so that what i am not catching... my fellow members can help me out doing this in more efficient manner... hope if you have any smart solution for this... you will share... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @WillVousden I have edited it to give the insight that its working for month 11 also.... enjoy and cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for this:

```
$time = strtotime('+3 months');
```

However, you should be aware that your problem doesn't really have an answer, since a "month" – in the colloquial sense – is not a well-defined unit of time. For example, what is the 31st of March plus three months? There's no such date as the 31st of June.

In the example given above, any "extra" days will roll over into the next month, so for the 31st of March [you'll get the 1st of July](http://codepad.org/yz4XB5P2). This behaviour is arbitrary, and weather you consider it "correct" is up to you. If you write your own implementation, you'll have to decide how to handle these cases yourself.

Comment: Will it be able to deal with the issue... i have in my edited portion... I know i had not explained the question properly...

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P3M'));
```

Answer (score -2):

Example from [the PHP manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

```
$lastmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"),   date("Y"));
```

So try:

```
$lastmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+3,  date("d"),   date("Y"));
```

Comment: That's not a wise thing to do. What if today is January 31? April doesn't have 31 days.

Comment: What happens if it's December? 15th month of the year?